# Include outputs in README.md

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, markdown

In my Rails app, I list its dependencies on README.md, e.g. Ruby 2.3.3, Bundler, NodeJS, Yarn, etc.

Is there a way to include the version of each dependency software, coming from `<software> -v` or `<software> --version` automatically, without having me to manually write it down?

The code in README.md would ideally be, for example:

```
* Ruby 2.3.3
* Bundler 1.16.6
* NodeJS v8.9.1
* Yarn 1.13.0
```

and so on.

Comment: Are these dependencies for development or for release?  You could either write a shell script which gets the versions for things you're interested in or use something like Vagrant to allow other developers to set up a development environment.

Comment: It's for development. How would I run the shell script? Each time a dependency version is updated?

Comment: Have you looked into your Gemfile.lock ? You have all the versions there

Comment: @tsrandrei thanks but I'm looking for a way to write the versions into my README.md, and not of gems, but of programs my app depends on, like NodeJS, Yarn etc.